# I think of making www-data available for direct usage, and to merge another user into it

Tags: permissions, apache2

Let's assume that I created the system I created a user name *tiesto*. I basically had *root*, and *tiesto* as the users I operate directly.

Then when I installed Apache, it added a third user - *www-data*.

When I run `ps aux | egrep '(apache|httpd)'` I get:

```
root      3192  0.0  1.4 327668 30364 ?        Ss   Nov23   0:04 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 28806  0.0  2.1 335512 43696 ?        S    06:25   0:01 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 28808  0.0  1.8 335196 37412 ?        S    06:25   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 28809  0.0  2.0 337408 41280 ?        S    06:25   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 28811  0.0  2.3 333112 49148 ?        S    06:25   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 32351  0.2  2.3 341040 49028 ?        S    06:50   0:01 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 32480  0.0  0.5 328160 10844 ?        S    06:58   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 32481  0.0  0.5 328280 11128 ?        S    06:58   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 32482  0.2  1.8 335116 37428 ?        S    06:58   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 32483  0.0  1.7 334784 36040 ?        S    06:58   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 32484  0.0  0.4 327716  8812 ?        S    06:59   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
tiesto   32586  0.0  0.0  14512  1032 pts/0    S+   07:01   0:00 grep -E --color=auto (apache|httpd)
```

---

### My question:

Well, my question can be comprised of the following 2 questions:

1. Why when I do `su www-data`, I get:

> This account is currently not available.

2. How could I merge *tiesto* with *www-data*? (i.e directory inodes, cron-tasks, etc)? I just want to take everything besides the username *tiesto*, and put in *www-data*, then delete *tiesto*... I want *www-data* to be my working user, the one I do `sudo anything` with, and not *tiesto*. I could call this **merging** *tiesto* ---> into *www-data*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`www-data` is a system account, intended to be used as the account under which Apache HTTP Server runs. It is *not* intended to be used for interactive work.

The direct technical answer to the question why `su www-data` does not work is that the account `www-data` is set to have `nologin` as its login shell (`man nologin`). This is done by default in order to discourage using that account for interactive work. You can of course always do `sudo -u www-data bash` if you absolutely must; but I can't see why it would be necessary.

On systems derived from Debian, Apache runs by default under the user `www-data`. To make it run under another user account you must edit the file `/etc/apache2/envvars`. Look for `export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data` and `export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data` and change them to match your requirements.

Running the web server under your account may or may not have security implications depending on the specific setup. A better way may be to let Apache run under `www-data` (to restrict its permissions) and change the ownership of the directories served by Apache to your account. Directories where apache is to have write access can be made owned by user `www-data` and your group, with the set-group-id bit set and write access for the group.

Now, if you *still* insist that you want your *interactive* account to be called `www-data` the simplest way is to take ownership of all files owned by account `www-data` or group `www-data`, delete the account and group `www-data`, then rename your account and main group `www-data`. I will not explain in detail how to perform this useless, complicated and error-prone procedure.